# Can't find Element inside HTML <object>

Tags: javascript, html

We're using an `<object>`-Tag to embed an SVG-Graphic. Now I would like to find an element inside this SVG-XML-Text using `document.querySelector`.

The call always returns `null`. Interestingly enough, if I use F12-DevTools (Chrome) and try to select the element with the same call in the console, it also returns `null` unless I expand the DOM in the Element-Hierarchy-View of the DevTools (by clicking). After I did that, the `document.querySelector` returns the Element I'm looking for.

Is there a way to "expand" the object from JavaScript so it is searchable with a querySelector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that if I first try to find the `object` and use it's `contentWindow.document`, then it will work:

`document.querySelector('object').contentDocument.querySelector('[objId="xyz"]');`